# prove that $f_n$ a sequence of holomorphic functions is a Normal family

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions

let $f_n=u_n+v_n$ be a sequence of  holomorphic functions  on $D(0,1)$ that are continuous on $ \overline {D(0,1)}$.Suppose that sequence $\{u_n\}$ converges uniformaly on $\partial D(0,1)$ and the sequence $\{f_n(0)\}$ converge.show that $\mathcal{F}=\{f_n|n=1,2,3,.....\}$ is normal family.

how to approach this problem. Do we need Montel theorem to prove this family is Normal ??? please help.Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: Did you mean $f_n = u_n + i v_n?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Schwartz integral formula (see this Wikipedia [link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_integral_formula)). The sequence will converge uniformly on compact subsets of the disk.

Comment: mean will show $f_n$ is uniformly cauchy on compact subsets of disk

Comment: @Eklavya: that will imply they converge to a holomoprhic function.

Comment: that also mean $f_n$ is normal family ??

Comment: @Eklavya: it will certainly imply that